# STS - Can't Find Grails Library

Tags: grails, groovy, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am porting over Grails project to STS and I don't know much about the project nor about STS, so I am a little lost.  Also of note is that the project was previously in Grails 1.0.3 and I am upgrading it to 1.3.7.

After loading in the existing code, I configured my project to use Grails 1.3.7.  When I attempt to build the project I get a bunch of errors relating to what appears to be just basic grails code that should come with 1.3.7:
e.g. `Groovy:unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder`

Also, when I open STS I am asked to run an "upgrade" for grails, which fails with the following:

```
Command terminated with an error code (see details for output)
------System.out:-----------
 Welcome to Grails 1.3.7 - http://grails.org/
Licensed under Apache Standard License 2.0
Grails home is set to: /home/devon/springsource/grails-1.3.7/

Base Directory: /home/devon/Documents/Source/trunk
Resolving dependencies...
Dependencies resolved in 2458ms.
Running script /home/devon/springsource/grails-1.3.7/scripts/Compile.groovy
Environment set to development
Setting non-interactive mode
  [groovyc] Compiling 110 source files to /home/devon/.grails/1.3.7/projects/trunk/classes
  [groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
  [groovyc] /tmp/groovy-generated-1742177078522700179-java-source/com/pps/domain/User.java:62: package org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service does not exist
  [groovyc] public  org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService getAuthenticateService() { return (org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService)null;}
  [groovyc]                                                  ^
  [groovyc] /tmp/groovy-generated-1742177078522700179-java-source/com/pps/domain/User.java:63: package org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service does not exist
  [groovyc] public  void setAuthenticateService(org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService value) { }
  [groovyc]                                                                              ^
  [groovyc] /home/devon/Documents/Source/trunk/src/java/com/pps/util/MarketplaceWidgetUtils.java:24: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
  [groovyc] import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
  [groovyc]                ^
  [groovyc] /tmp/groovy-generated-1742177078522700179-java-source/com/pps/domain/User.java:62: package org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service does not exist
  [groovyc] public  org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService getAuthenticateService() { return (org.grails.plugins.springsecurity.service.AuthenticateService)null;}
  [groovyc]                                                                                                                                                   ^
  [groovyc] /home/devon/Documents/Source/trunk/src/java/com/pps/util/MarketplaceWidgetUtils.java:170: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
  [groovyc]             BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
  [groovyc]             ^
  [groovyc] /home/devon/Documents/Source/trunk/src/java/com/pps/util/MarketplaceWidgetUtils.java:170: warning: sun.misc.BASE64Encoder is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
  [groovyc]             BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
  [groovyc]                                         ^
  [groovyc] 3 errors
  [groovyc] 3 warnings
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] 
  [groovyc] 1 error
Compilation error: Compilation Failed

------System.err:-----------
```

In my Java Build Path I have a 'Grails Dependencies' folder, but I don't know how to change it to make sure it is pointing to the right dependencies.  There is also 'Groovy Libraries' and a bunch of random '.jar' dependencies.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it wasn't finding it because required dependencies to plugins were not resolving correctly.  Once I got the plugins it worked correctly.

Comment: Did you issue a grails command to download all the dependencies, or did you run Grails Tools|Refresh Dependencies from the STS Project Explorer context menu?  Were you missing the dependencies, or did you just need to point them out to STS?

Comment: @Jim Norman - I ran them from the STS menu.  I was not missing the dependencies - they just weren't linked up correctly for whatever reason.